# Spring boot - To execute statement sql update (JPA)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just have started with Spring Boot and I am practicing in base to this example:
http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

The physical deleted is working ok, but I am trying to do a logical deleted and I do not know how to do it.

This is my classes:

UserController

```
@DeleteMapping(path ={"logical/{id}"})
public User deleteLogical(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody User user) {
    return userService.deleteLogical(id, user);
}
```

UserService

```
User deleteLogical(int id, User user);
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Override
// @Query("update user set remove = false where id = ?1")
public User deleteLogical(int id, User user) {
    // user.setRemove(false);
    return repository.save(user);
}
```

UserRepository

```
User save(User user);
```

This is the SQL statement I want to execute:

```
UPDATE user SET remove = false WHERE id =?;
```

How I could do it? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need to pass User object. Id will be  enough.

So your code will be changed

```
@DeleteMapping(path ={"logical/{id}"})
public User deleteLogical(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return userService.deleteLogical(id, user);
}
```

UserService

```
User deleteLogical(int id);
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Override
public User deleteLogical(int id) {
    User user = repository.findById(id);
    user.setRemove(true);
    return repository.save(user);
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You try to implement "soft delete" so you can try this approach:

**User entity**:

```
@Entity
User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    //...

    private boolean removed; // user is removed if this property is true

    //...
}
```

**User service**:

```
public interface UserService {   
    Optional<Integer> softDelete(int id);
}

@Service    
public UserServiceImpl implements UserService (

   // Injecting UserRepo

   // First variant - read the user, set it removed, then updated it.
   @Transactional
   Optional<Integer> softDelete1(int id) {
       // Using method findById from Spring Boot 2+, for SB1.5+ - use method findOne 
       return userRepo.findById(id).map(user -> {
           user.setRemoved(true); 
           userRepo.save(user);
           return 1;
       });
   }

   // Second variant - update the user directly
   @Transactional
   Optional<Integer> softDelete2(int id) {
       return userRepo.softDelete(id);
   }
}
```

**User controller**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

   // Injecting UserService

   @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
   public ResponseEntity<?> softDelete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return userService.softDelete1(id) // you can use 1 or 2 variants 
            .map(i -> ResponseEntity.noContent().build()) // on success
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()); // if user not found
   }
}
```

**User repo**:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>() {
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("update User u set u.removed = true where u.id = ?1")
    int remove(int id);

    default Optional<Integer> softDelete(int id) {
        return (remove(id) > 0) ? Optional.of(1) : Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Or, I think, you can just try to simply override the `deleteById` method of `CrudRepository` (not tested - please give a feedback):

```
@Override
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update User u set u.removed = true where u.id = ?1")
void deleteById(Integer id);
```

then use it in your service.

Comment: This information is more complete, thanks, when I will checked it, I'll leave a comment